# Add Android Dependencies to non-Android Project in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, build.gradle

Is there a something special you need to do in order to import Android dependencies into a non-Android Gradle project in Eclipse?  I'm trying to make a project in Eclipse where I can develop some classes with Android dependencies, export them to a JAR, then import them into my Android Studio project to use them.  I'm not trying to create a standalone app.  I just want to make components that I can import.

For example, most of the RecyclerViews I make in Android Studio are about 90% the same as all the other ones I make, so I want to make a class that extends RecyclerView with the options I most commonly use.  This is the build.gradle I'm trying.  I just cut and pasted the dependencies from my Android project build.gradle but that doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()

}

dependencies {

    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: you want to develop in android studio or eclipse?

Comment: I like Eclipse, but I'd use Android Studio if it can't be done in Eclipse

Comment: I'm using Android Studio for Android apps, but I'd like to use Eclipse for Android components

Comment: in starting i also use Eclipse but Android studio is mostly use now a day, i suggest to use Android studio

Comment: you can use android studio for Android components